# Plural form of titles

Tags: grammatical-number

I've heard certain titles pluralised in apparently odd ways, such as a [Secretary General](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary-General) being [Secretaries General](http://www.un.org/sg/formersgs.shtml) when plural, rather than "Secretary Generals" as I'd have guessed, and I'm wondering if there's a rule on this. For example if you were addressing two female Presidents, would is be "Madames President" (multiple females who preside over something) or "Madame Presidents" (multiple Presidents who are female)?

Comment: The general question is general reference: just look up articles on 'plurals of compound nouns', eg at Wikipedia. The honorific is a different construction; [Mesdames President](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1842&dat=19620805&id=hB8sAAAAIBAJ&sjid=rsYEAAAAIBAJ&pg=829,3821495) has been used.

Comment: The Secretary General is a type of Secretary. You pluralize the noun, not the adjective.  Similar to Sergeant Major...this is a kind of Sergeant, not a type of Major, so would be pluralized as Sergeants Major.  You wouldn't be confused about how to pluralize a 'blue car'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *general* in *attorney general*, *surgeon general*, etc., is actually a [postpositive adjective](http://grammarist.com/grammar/postpositive-adjectives/) (i.e., an adjective that comes *after* the noun it modifies). The *general*, therefore, is the adjective general and has nothing to do with the military rank.

Edit: For the plural of Madam President, the plural would be *[Mesdames](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/madam?show=1&t=1401306249) Presidents*; one is an [honorific](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honorific), one is a title, and *both* would be pluralized.

Answer (score 0):

Theodore has it right. You would pluralize Presidents, just as you would say Honorable Justices of the Court.

Comment: Although I appreciate your positive response, [EL&U's strict rules on answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) proscribe adding comments like this as a separate answer. Instead, you should earn up the reputation required to comment on and upvote answers. By writing your own good answers, you should have those privileges in no time!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just earned enough rep to comment about two minutes before this.  I am obviously new to the forum and am still learning the ropes.